# Can somebody explain why is this datetime comparsion showing output the way it is in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm parsing an atom feed. There is an updated tag in the feed. It's value is **2012-05-20T02:24:56Z**. I insert this information in a table in this manner.

```
cursor.execute('Insert into Timing (LastUpdatedTime) Values(?)',
                (testFeed.feed.updated,))
```

After that I obtain the value from table and convert it into datetime in this way

```
cursor.execute("Select LastUpdatedTime from Timing")
lastUpdatedTime=datetime.strptime(list(cursor.fetchone())[0],
                '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').isoformat()
```

The value of lastUpdatedTime is **2012-05-20T02:24:56**

Now when I compare the value of testFeed.feed.updated with lastUpdatedTime to check if the feed had any new entries my comparison is giving output which I fail to comprehend.

```
print testFeed.feed.updated == lastUpdatedTime
```

This returns false
    print testFeed.feed.updated > lastUpdatedTime

This returns true.
Values of variables when comparing:
testFeed.feed.updated=**2012-05-20T02:24:56Z**
lastUpdatedTime=**2012-05-20T02:24:56**

The column in database is of type text.

type of testFeed.feed.updated is unicode

type of lastUpdatedTime is string

Using python 2.7.2, working on Ubuntu 11.10

It works after converting the unicode object to datetime
`currentFeedTime=datetime.strptime(str(testfeed.feed.updated),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').isoformat()` and then to do the comparison with previous time.

Comment: What are the types of appropriate columns in the database? What do you see, when you print `type(some_date)` executed on each variable?

Comment: @Tadeck updated with the outputs of the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing makes sense to me, since `testFeed.feed.updated` has an extra 'Z' at the end.

Having said that, if you're doing date/time comparison, I think you're better off converting both dates to `datetime.datetime`, so something along the lines of:

For `lastUpdatedTime`

```
cursor.execute("Select LastUpdatedTime from Timing")
# Note that I'm not converting this to a string.
lastUpdatedTime=datetime.strptime(list(cursor.fetchone())[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

And instead of `testFeed.feed.updated`:

```
feedUpdatedTime=datetime.strptime(testFeed.feed.updated,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

And then to compare the two:

```
print feedUpdatedTime == lastUpdatedTime
```

Comment: And it would be even better if the database field were a datetime instead of a text

Comment: Agreed, that would eliminate the need to parse the date in Python when reading from the database.